# Insert to tail for linked list in C++ not working correctly

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list

Here is my implementation of the insert to tail function in C++:

```
void List::InsertBack(int x)
{
    Node *temp = root;
    Node *nNode = new Node(x);

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        temp = nNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp = nNode;
    }
}
```

When I call the function list1.InsertBack(10) and then print out the linked list it shows as empty.
However, if I change

```
if (temp == NULL)
{
    temp = nNode;
}
```

to

```
if (temp == NULL)
{
    root = nNode;
}
```

then it works and prints out the 10 just fine. Any idea what is going on? Is there something about pointers in C++ that I am just not understanding?

Comment: `root` is a member instance variable of your List, whereas the scope of `temp` is just within that function. When you re-assign `temp`, it is not re-assigning `root`. When you print the List, it uses `root`'s pointer value, which has not been changed.

Comment: `temp` only has scope within the function `List::InsertBack` whereas `root` has scope that persists with the object it belongs to.

Comment: When you inserted the node, you have not maintained the links to the new node.  BTW, maintaining a pointer to the last node will remove the need to traverse the list to get to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node* temp = root;
```

Here you're creating a copy of the `root` pointer and initializing it with `temp`. Changes you make to the `temp` pointer does not affect `root` at all. So when you do:

```
temp = nNode;
```

This only changes what the local variable `temp` points to, not what `root` itself points to. The correct way to modify `root` would be to assign to it itself:

```
root = nNode;
```

Note: If `temp` was a reference to a pointer then the code would work.

Next, when you append to a linked list you have to find the last node that has a `next` equal to `NULL`. Once you have that node you need to update its `next` pointer, so the correct way to iterate would be like this:

```
while (temp->next)
    temp = temp->next;
temp->next = nNode;
```

The assignment at the end affects the actual node, not the pointer.

Comment: So then if I have to use root, then how do I add to the back without losing the head of the linked list?

Comment: @James4701 I'm not saying to not use `temp` at all. `temp` is useful because you need shallow access to the pointers. You use `temp` to iterate through the list to find the last node and then update its `next` pointer. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a191a8a0e01f3b3

Comment: OK so this fixed it and it works now. I still don't quite understand something though. Howcome when I try to set temp = nNode when the list is empty that does NOT affect root, but then when I am just adding to the list with temp->next = nNode, then that does affect root?

Comment: @James4701 Good question. `ptr->x` is the same `(*ptr).x`. When you use the `*` operator on a pointer, it returns a *reference* to the object it points to. A reference is like an alias for that object - changes you make to the reference affect the actual object. So doing `ptr->x = y` changes the `x` data member of the object pointed to by `ptr` to `y`.

Comment: OK I understand that. So when I first say Node *temp = root; that is telling temp to point to the address of root (assuming root is instantiated as Node *root). So when I say temp = nNode then it is no longer pointing to root and now pointing to nNode which is just local. Is there any way to set root to nNode using temp?

Comment: @James4701 `Node* temp = root` means to have `temp` point to the same thing that `root` points to. `temp` is not an alias for `root` (because it's not a reference). Doing `temp = nNode` says make `temp` now point to `nNode`, it does not affect `root` at all. The way to make `temp` be an alias for `root` is to make it a reference: `Node*& temp = root`. Now doing `temp = nNode` affects `root` (but if you incorporate this into your `InsertBack()` method then you'll have a nasty bug! :)

Answer (score 1):

You define two local variables in your code, `nNode` and `temp`.

As `temp` is the only thing you change, never the member (`root`) it was initialized from, it's no wonder nothing changes.
Aside from producing a memory-leak each time you call the function.

Change `temp` to a `Node**`, and initialize it with the address of `root` (the first candidate-place for pointing to the new node):

```
void List::InsertBack(int x) {
    Node **temp = &root;
    while(*temp) // As long as we don't point to the null-pointer we want to replace
        temp = &temp[0]->next; // move to the next node
    *temp = new Node(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

temp only exists in the scope of the function call, so when you set temp = nNode in the first case temp is destroyed at the end of the function. root exists outside of the function call so you need to set root= nNode

Answer (score 0):

You should change `while(temp != NULL)` to `while(temp->next != NULL)`
and `temp = nNode` to `temp->next = nNode`.

Alternatively `for (temp = root; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next);` is like forwarding your pointer.